# Segmentation fault in c - probably connected with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

When I add this function in my program, I get this error: "Segmentation fault". I have found that it is probably connected with pointers.

This is my function:

```
void deBoor(double* D, double* t, double x, int k, int n, double* R){
   int i,j,l;
   double ret[3];
   double* P=(double*)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
   for(i=0; i<n; ++i) P[i]=D[i];
   j=k;
   while(x<t[j]) ++j;
   while(x>=t[j+1]) ++j;
   for(l=1; l<=k; ++l){
       for(i=j; i>=j-k+l; --i)
       {
          P[i]=(x-t[i])/(t[i+k+1-l]-t[i])*P[i]+(t[i+k+1-l]-x)/(t[i+k+1-l]-t[i])*P[i-1];
       }
   }
   R[0]=P[j];
   free(P);
}
```

And this is the call of the function:

```
deBoor (kontrolne_tocke, prosirena_particija, xx, k, duljina, R);
```

Comment: I hardly dare ask, but: did you debug?

Comment: Start up gdb or some other debugger and see where the fault is. Also create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're still stuck.

Comment: Yes, I did. No errors are shown, and when I execute it then part of my code just print results, and at the part of that function is written "Segmentation fault"

Comment: Then read up on how to debug, e.g. set breakpoints at various points in the code and see where the segmentation fault occurs (at what instruction)

Comment: You don't check your inputs at all. How do you know that R[1] or R[2] are valid? Note that the value of the parameter n is critical and other parameters must have been correctly allocated so that accesses to them are valid. I am left to believe that all this has been done in the caller code. And I don't believe it.

Comment: Which line gives the seg fault? What are the values of `x`, `k` and `n` in the function. What's the unused variable `ret` doing in the code? Your pair of loops incrementing `j` look like a plausible source of trouble; you go incrementing `j` without caring (knowing?) how big the array is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is rather unsafe. Some issues, not only about the safety but some of these certainly can cause your crash:

1. Input arguments should be `const` pointers, for clarity.
2. The return value of `malloc()` is not checked, so if the allocation fails you're toast.
3. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).
4. Don't copy using a loop, use `memcpy()`.
5. There's no guarantee that `j` doesn't go out of bounds.
6. The `ret` array is never used.

Comment: Also potential division by zero.

Comment: j went out of bound. Thank you :)